# Xtext: Reference a Java class from MyDsl

Tags: java, enums, reference, xtext, xbase

In my DSL, I want to have a code that looks like:

```
SomeType varName;
```

Where `SomeType` is a Java class.

Later on, if lets say SomeType is an enum java-class, and someone writes

```
varName=SOME_VALUE
```

I want to do a validation to see if SomeType.java actually has `SOME_VALUE` as a value in its enum.
I saw this tutorial 
https://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/305_xbase.html

but I'm not sure this is what I need (I need to import .mydsl files, not only jvm). 
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: well this question is quite unspecific. what about simply doing some experiments with xbase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want references to Java types, use `org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xtype` as super-grammar. Then you can write a rule like

```
VariableDeclaration:
    type=JvmTypeReference name=ValidID ';';
```

to express your code sample.

If you also want to express assignments, I suggest to use `org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase` as super-grammar (which inherits from Xtype) and use the XExpression rule wherever you want to reference elements from Java, e.g.

```
VariableAssignment:
    variable=[VariableDeclaration|ValidId] '=' expression=XExpression;
```

To make things easier, you could also use XExpression for variable declarations (XVariableDeclaration is a special XExpression) and for assignments (XAssignment is another special XExpression). That would allow to write stuff like

```
{
    var SomeType varName
    varName = SomeType.SOME_VALUE
}
```

with a single call to XBlockExpression (a composite expression surrounded by curly braces):

```
MyFunkyRule:
    ...
    expressionBlock=XBlockExpression
    ...
```